# How to initialize a member of type glm::vec<D, T, glm::highp> in a constructor of a class with template parameters D and T?

Tags: c++, templates, glm-math

I have an unfinished class `MyClass` that wraps `glm::vec`:

```
template <typename T, int D>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(???)
    : myVec(???)
    {
        /* Do stuff */
    }

private:
    glm::vec<D, T, glm::highp> myVec;
};
```

I want to finish the constructor such that the constructor works as the constructor for `glm::vec3` for `D` = 3 and as the constructor for `glm::vec4` for `D` = 4. What should I write instead of `???` (at each of the places)?

Comment: [Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @Rabbid76 One problem with that approach is that the constructor signature becomes very non-informative. It neither tells the user how many arguments to enter, nor of which type the arguments should be.

Comment: @Rabbid76 And what if I would have had two `glm::vec` members that both needed to be initialized? Would I be able to take two parameter packs as arguments to the same function? I guess not, since I don’t know how the compiler would know where one parameter pack ended and the other one started, right? Or would I be able to split up one parameter pack into two equally long parts somehow?

Comment: [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks; I used a form of template specialization (I guess you could say) that was based on `std::enable_if` since the different specializations take differently many arguments. I guess I could also use `std::enable_if` or `std::enable_if_t` to check if the elements in a parameter pack were of the correct type and of the correct amount, but I dread the obfuscation of the resulting code I imagine that would lead to.